# Applying style in tags with javascript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to apply `display: inline;` for every `li` in the page using javascript. Is there a way to do it?
I can't use jQuery.

It will be like:

```
li{
    display: inline; 
}
```

It's kind a simple problem, but I don't know why I didn't find it at google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `document.getElementsByTagName("li");`

```
var elements=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var x=0;x<elements.length;x++){
    elements[x].style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: yeah... I'd like to know when I add `li` dynamically too... that's gonna work for only those that already exist. But the question is marked as duplicate and is malformed cause I didn't say about the dynamically insert, just let implicitly with that css code... I'll mark as answer.

Comment: when you add a `li` dinamically simply give it the `inline` style with `newLI.style.display="inline";`

Comment: I was trying to avoid it. The question is really malformed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName` and `style` property of `Element` and looping can be done using `Array.forEach`, though we need to use `Function.call` as the returned object of `getElementsByTagName` isn't an actually array but a `NodeList`

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("li"), function(elm){
   elm.style.display = "inline";
})
```